# Strange output in apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am facing a strange problem in apache tomcat.Suppose when I load a class in jsp file it gives me output but when i change the java file recompile changing class file the changes are not shown by apache tomcat,it shows result of previous class...for eg:

```
<html>
<head><title>Hello World</title></head>
<body>
Hello World!<br/>   
<%@ page import="neww.Simpl" %>
<% Simpl demo = new Simpl();
    out.println("Current date : " + demo.retur());%>
<%
out.println("Your IP addresssavxcd is " + request.getRemoteAddr());
%>
</body>
</html>
```

for the first time it shows correct result now if I change the Simpl.java and recompile it and run this jsp file again tomcat gives me previous result.
P.S. I am sure that the class file is modified.

Comment: Restart Server and Try again.

Comment: are you working through some sort of IDE? (eclipse, idea, netbeans...) how are you deploying your code to tomcat ?

Comment: m not using any IDE...my class file is under WEB-INF/classes/neww/

Comment: Restarting also doesnot help..

Comment: stop tomcat, delete /temp and /work subdirectories' contents, and start it up again. see if that helps

Comment: I tried that already but no help!! I even tried deleting the class file  but then to it gives same output.....

Comment: Can you do a change in the JSP code and try again? The class which you have re-compiled is not loaded in the server. A change in JSP will trigger I hope so.

Comment: when I  change the class name and make a new java file and change the jspcode likewise it works..but I cannot do this everytime I want to change my java code....

Comment: what is eclipse and tomcat versions you are using?

Comment: I am not using eclipse and tomcat version is 8.0.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is something wrong with what you are doing.  In particular:

> stop tomcat, delete /temp and /work subdirectories' contents, and start it up again.
>
> I tried that already but no help!! I even tried deleting the class file but then to it gives same output.....

If you deleted the old compiled JSP class file, the work and temp directories and restarted the server .... and still saw the old behaviour, then something must be replacing the new version of the JSP *source code* with the old version.  The only plausible explanation for that is that you are modifying the JSP in-place, and a redeploy (from the WAR?) is clobbering your tweaks.  But a redeploy shouldn't happen spontaneously.  You must be doing something to cause it.

The only other explanation I can think of is that you are deleting the wrong JSP class files, and it is hard to envisage how that might be happening.

Comment: Actually there is no problem with jsp code...if I modify jsp code the output changes accordingly..but the problem is when I change class file the output remains same.........

Comment: In that case, you are probably not deploying the new version of the class to the server .... in the correct way.

Comment: I have only one copy of class in the folder and I recompiled the java code which modifies the class..I don't understand how could the server still gets the previous class?

Comment: The server won't see the new class unless it is told to redeploy the webapp.  A JVM normally only loads a class once.  If you change the class after it has been loaded, the JVM won't notice the new version.

Comment: @user3654540 The described behaviour is *not possible*. Either you are not properly restarting Tomcat, replacing class file or you have tampered with class loading and your are replacing incorrect class file.

Comment: @StephenC Hoe can I redeploy the webapp?

Comment: Try using some IDE,It handles the redeployment issues and many other overheads itself.Everytime when you will make any modifications to your jsp file,The IDE will reflect the changes by redeployment

Comment: Tomcat can be configured to auto-reload a web application if class files or JAR files change. You want to set the `reloadable` attribute on your `<Context>` element in `META-INF/context.xml` to `true` and then Tomcat will auto-reload your web application when your classes change. You might want to disable this in production.